# Jenkins: Set job timeout from a variable in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timeout, pipeline, jobs

I premise that I am not very familiar with Jenkins and Groovy.
I am trying to set a timeout with a time value that can change based on a specific condition. I was wondering if it is possible to do this and how.

This is a shortened example for simplicity, of the pipeline I'm dealing with:

```
/**
 * prepare tests for parallel
 * @param filename Name of the file that contains the testsuites list
 */
def doDynamicParallelSteps(filename){
    tests = [:]
    echo "doDynamicParallelSteps"
    def w = pwd()
    def path = "$w/$filename"
    // read all the lines into a list, each line is an element in the list
    def fh = new File(path)
    def lines = fh.readLines()
    for (line in lines) {
        def values = line.split(":")
        def testsuite_name = values[0].trim()
        def test_path = values[1].trim()
        def test_filename_or_directory = test_path.split("/").getAt(-1);
        def is_file = test_filename_or_directory.matches("(.*).php")
        def is_custom_mycondition = test_filename_or_directory.matches("MyMatchCondition")
        if (is_custom_mycondition){ // large timeout
            def time_val = 10
        } else { // default timeout
            def time_val = 5
        }
        tests["${test_filename_or_directory}"] = {
            stage("UnitTest ${test_filename_or_directory}") {
                timeout(time: time_val, unit: 'MINUTES') { // scripted syntax
                    // other stuff here
                } // end timeout
            } // end stage
        } // end MAP
    }
    parallel tests
}
```

If I run this pipeline I got the following output:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: time_val for class: mycustomJob

Then I've tried to set it as global value and it worked but not as expected, because its value doesn't seems to changed, it outputs "5" ignoring my condition.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone show me the right way or a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks more pythonic than groovy. You must define the variable 'time_val' on a higher level to make it visible in your scope, like:

```groovy
def time_val = 5
if (is_custom_mycondition){ // large timeout
    time_val = 10
}
```

Instead of your else part.
You can also define it in a single line, like:

```groovy
def time_val = is_custom_mycondition ? 10 : 5
```

Your 'timeout' usage looks correct to me. Just define the variable properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable advice, now it seems to be working as planned.

Anyway I was unaware of the possibility of using the ternary operator here, now that you have taught me I will use it.